# How to copy network credentials from PEAP authenticated computer to a new PC

Tags: networking, security

**Backstory**

I'm a student on our school's school network. There's three tears of network at our school. There's the Student network which the student iPads are connected to. We don't have the keys, but I was able to extract the WPA2 code and connect my own devices. The internet is just slow because of all of the iPads that are connected. The network traffic is slow on the 'student' network. There's the educator network key which I got from a school computer I have special access to. I'm a lighting designer, and needed an internet connected PC. The IT guy gave me one, and I extracted the WPA2 key. I can connect my devices to the network using that key, and the IT guy knows about it. It's not much faster though, and he actually cares about the devices on that network, and he can easily catch me probably through ICMP protocols and a bunch of other ways. He doesn't want me connecting to it. The other option is the 'radius' network. My school-issued crappy laptop has also been given the credentials to this network. This is very long-range, and the network is supposed to be slower, but since there's no traffic on it, it's actually speedy. No one uses it, because it's intended to extend to the football field, soccer, base ball fields. That's the reason for its existence. It's got some more fancy security for some reason, and I've heard that the IT guy doesn't care about it as much. However, it uses some unfamiliar PEAP authentication, meaning I can't just copy and paste the key. That's the one I want to put on my personal laptop which has much better specs than the 8 year old i3, 4gb Ram PC I'm using now to use this network. The IT guy will probably just tell me to use the Student network (which he knows I have), which is too slow.

**Actual Question**
How can I copy a PEAP authenticated network profile from one PC from my school connected PC to my personal laptop? When Windows says the network is AES encrypted, does that mean that the authentication certificate is encrypted or the network traffic? Is there a way to extract a WPA2 password from the certificate. I have administrator access on the school PC, and obviously administrator access on my personal laptop. If I don't know how enterprise network authentication works, is this even worth my time?

Thanks Superuser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEAP has options for what kind of login credentials it uses. It can use usernames and passwords or it can use public key certificates and their matching private keys.

The credentials can be stored in the user accounts, or they can be stored in a system-wide location so the machine can be on the network even when no user is logged in (like for remote management and overnight backups).

You can see what public key certificates are installed by using certmgr.mmc, which is the Certificate Manager snap-in for the Microsoft Management Console. You can use that tool to export certificates, and, in some cases, also export their matching private keys, which are a necessary part of the login credentials. You can't use a cert to auth to a network if you don't have the private key that goes with it.

If the private key you need was marked as non-exportable when it was installed, Microsoft's tools won't let you export it. However, there are third party tools that can help you extract non-exportable private keys out of the certificate store, if you have the right level of access to the PC. IIRC, you need to know the local admin password.

Comment: Do you know what 'folder' in the cert manager holds the WiFi certs? Or how to figure out which cert is used by which network?